# Error in integrating a complex-valued function over a square in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

I have a **complex-valued** function `func(x, y)`, which is well defined for any `x` and `y` values.

```
func = @(x, y) (eps_func(x, y)*[1+1i, 1-2i, 3])*([4+3i, 6-2i, 3+1i])';
```

where `eps_func()` is basically a binary function. If `(x, y)` falls into a circle, it returns 15. Otherwise, return 1.

```
function eps_val = eps_func(x, y)

SQ_SIDE_LEN = 2;
C_RADIUS = 0.11*SQ_SIDE_LEN;

dist_from_origin = sqrt(x.^2+y.^2);
if dist_from_origin <= C_RADIUS % inside the circle
    eps_val = 15;
else % outside the circle
    eps_val = 1;
end
end
```

I now wish to integrate it over the `x-y` square (`-1 ≤ x ≤ 1` and `-1 ≤ y ≤ 1`) in MATLAB. I did

```
U1 = integral2(func, -1, 1, -1, 1);
```

which returns me this error

```
Error using integral2Calc>integral2t/tensor (line 242)
Integrand output size does not match the input size.

Error in integral2Calc>integral2t (line 56)
[Qsub,esub] = tensor(thetaL,thetaR,phiB,phiT);

Error in integral2Calc (line 10)
    [q,errbnd] =
    integral2t(fun,xmin,xmax,ymin,ymax,optionstruct);

Error in integral2 (line 107)
    Q =
    integral2Calc(fun,xmin,xmax,yminfun,ymaxfun,opstruct);

Error in chern (line 24)
            U1 = integral2(func, -1, 1, -1, 1);
```

Where went wrong, and how can I fix it?

Comment: can you post the function?

Comment: If you just changed the function to be real-valued, just to test, does it work? That should nail down whether it's the complex output that's the problem, or if it's some error in your input sizes. Matlab's `integral` function allows complex values, so I would think `integral2` also allows complex values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that the issue is due to complexity. I know that `integral` handles complex integration just fine for example. The actual problem may be that your integrand does not meet the requirements specified in the documentation for [`integral2`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/integral2.html). The help states

> All input functions must accept arrays as input and operate
>       elementwise. The function Z = FUN(X,Y) must accept arrays X and Y of
>       the same size and return an array of corresponding values.

Your function, `eps_val`, certainly accepts arrays, but it always returns a scalar regardless of the size of the input. `integral2` is optimized to take advantage of vectorization so it passes in multiple values simultaneously and expects to see corresponding outputs, which doesn't happen in your case.

You may be able to resolve this by changing this block

```
if dist_from_origin <= C_RADIUS % inside the circle
    eps_val = 15;
else % outside the circle
    eps_val = 1;
end
```

to

```
eps_val = 14*(dist_from_origin <= C_RADIUS) + 1;
```

`dist_from_origin` is actually a vector the same size as `x` and `y`. Previously you were just using the first value of this vector for your `if` statement because of the absence of an `any` or `all`. The new one-liner returns a vector of 15's and 1's int the appropriate places.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this directly in Matlab as `integral2` expects a real-valued function.

You can just integrate the real and complex parts of the function separately and add them up.

Comment: Are you sure doing them separately and add them up in the end is the correct way of doing complex integral?

Comment: I think it is, if the domain is real like in your case.